# How to set filePermissions in log4j.properties file

Tags: java, logging, log4j

I am using slf4j-log4j12 latest version 1.7.25. We are using kibana to view logs, but the Kibana fails to read logs from tomcat. I need to set filePermissions to read files from tomcat in log4j.properties file.

```
filePermissions="rw-r-----"
```

My log4j.properties file,

```
# Put log messages in rolling log file
log4j.rootLogger=info, file
log4j.logger.com.sample=debug
log4j.appender.file=org.apache.log4j.DailyRollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.file.File=logs/MyService.log
log4j.appender.file.DatePattern='.'yyyy-MM-dd
log4j.appender.file.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.file.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{HH:mm:ss,SSS} %-5p %c{4} %M:%L - %m%n
```

Kindly provide your thoughts on this

Answer (score 1):

If I get your question right. 
Regarding official docs:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Configuration status="trace" name="MyApp" packages="">
  <Properties>
    <Property name="baseDir">logs</Property>
  </Properties>
  <Appenders>
    <RollingFile name="RollingFile" fileName="${baseDir}/app.log"
                 filePattern="${baseDir}/$${date:yyyy-MM}/app-%d{yyyyMMdd}.log.gz"
                 filePermissions="rw-------">
      <PatternLayout pattern="%d %p %c{1.} [%t] %m%n" />
      <CronTriggeringPolicy schedule="0 0 0 * * ?"/>
      <DefaultRolloverStrategy stopCustomActionsOnError="true">
        <PosixViewAttribute basePath="${baseDir}/$${date:yyyy-MM}" filePermissions="r--r--r--">
            <IfFileName glob="*.gz" />
        </PosixViewAttribute>
      </DefaultRolloverStrategy>
    </RollingFile>
  </Appenders>

  <Loggers>
    <Root level="error">
      <AppenderRef ref="RollingFile"/>
    </Root>
  </Loggers>

</Configuration>
```

Link: https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/appenders.html

It could be `log4j.appender.file.filePermissions=rw-------`   but it should be tested! 
The idea is that this attribute is configured as others.

Comment: I need this configuration in log4j.properties file. Can you provide this filePermissions for log4j.properties file?

Comment: I set this configuration in log4j.properties like "log4j.appender.file.filePermissions=rw-r------". But I couldn't see any changes under logs. I am not sure this property set properly.

Comment: The problem could be because of: 
properties doesn’t support advance configuration features like customhandler, nested appender like AsynchAppenders, etc, which we can achieve by using log4j.xml.

Comment: If you are using the latest version it could be the case to switch :)

Answer (score 0):

As per the docs this feature introduced in log4j 2.0 and as you mentioned you are still using 1.x.